# Integer $n>1$ such that the set of leading digits of the numbers $2^n ,3^n ,...,9^n$ is $\{2,3,...,9\} $

Tags: number-theory

For every $n \in \mathbb N$ , with $n=\sum_{j=0}^k 10^jn_j ; 0\le n_j \le 9 , n_k \ne 0$ , let us call $n_k$ to be the "leading digit" of $n$ . Does there exist integer $n>1$ such the set of leading digits of the integers $2^n ,3^n ,...,9^n$ is $\{2,3,...,9\}  $ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the portions of [Gelfand's Question](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GelfandsQuestion.html) and it is, as of now, unsolved.

Comment: Am I going mad, or isn't it possible to locate the leading digit of an $n^{th}$ power using logarithms to base $10$ - even moderately accurate logarithms would enable the tables of leading digits to be extended well beyond current values suggested in the useful link. The difficulty would seem to me to be more that $2,4,8$ are not independent of each other, nor are $3,9$, so the values for $2$ and $3$ are more constrained than they might otherwise be.

Comment: @MarkBennet , I have the same intuition too (I did not have time to check the references given by _mathworld.wolfram_ yet, there should be something there )